# np.where IndexError exception

Tags: python, numpy

I have a very simple code as following:

```
import numpy as np
num_classes = 12
im_pred = np.random.randint(0, num_classes, (224, 244))
img = np.zeros((224, 224, 3))
print(im_pred.shape)
#(224, 244)
print(img.shape)
#(224, 224, 3)
for i in range(num_classes):
    img[np.where(im_pred==i), :] = [225, 0, 0]
```

> Traceback (most recent call last):
>         File "", line 2, in <module>
>       IndexError: index 227 is out of bounds for axis 0 with size 224

```
x, y = np.where(im_pred==i)
print(np.max(x), np.max(y))
#223 243
```

Why I am getting an `IndexError`? As for my understanding of `np.where`, the values of indices returned should be less than `224`.

Let me know. I am starting to wonder if the `numpy` installation is buggy.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that you've made `img` and `img_pred` of different sizes:

```
im_pred.shape == (224, 244)
```

while

```
img.shape == (224, 224, 3)
```

The second axes have different sizes.

But once you fix that, there's a simple optimization to be made. There's no need for `np.where` here. Just use direct logical indexing:

```
for i in range(num_classes):
    img[im_pred == i, 0] = 255
```

Note I'm also leaving off the two zeros, since you initialize the array with zeros on construction.

Answer (score 1):

No Numpy is not buggy. Look at how you defined im_pred for a second, you are drawing a random integer between 0 and 11 for an array which has size 224 by 244. So the reason it is throwing an error is because the dimension of size 244 is too large for your variable img which is only 224 by 224 by 3.  I think you may have meant for both to have the same 1rst and second dimensions, something like

```
img = np.zeros((224,244,3))
```